# Is there a simple way to cram a large forest tree into a page or split it into two pages?

Tags: header-footer, page-breaking, forest

If I try to cram a large forest tree into a page by enlarging a page by 3 lines, I get the result below. The tree overlaps with the footer.

[image]

Below is the code. Is there a simple way to cram it in a page without allowing it to overlap with the footer? Or, is there a way to split it into two pages without complex tricks that I was introduced to previously?

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\bfseries\Alph*,align=left,leftmargin=*,
  labelsep=1.5em}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*.,labelindent=1em,labelsep=1.5em,
  leftmargin=*}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  ass/.append style={
    before computing xy={l=\baselineskip},
    no edge
  },
  prooftree/.style={
    baseline,
    for tree={
      child anchor=north,
      parent anchor=south
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Exercises 35}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Use \textbf{QL\textsuperscript{=}} trees to show the following inferences are valid:
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Jack is Fingers. Fingers is never caught. Whoever is never caught
    escapes justice. So Jack escapes justice.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [{$j=f$}
        [$\neg Cf$,ass
        [$\forall x(\neg Cx\supset Ex)$,ass
        [$\neg Ej$,ass
        [$(\neg Cf\supset Ef)$,ass
        [$\neg\neg Cf$ [*,ass]] [$Ef$
        [$Ej$,ass [*,ass]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item There is a wise philosopher. There is a philosopher who isn’t wise.
    So there are at least two philosophers.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\exists x(Fx\wedge Gx)\checkmark$
        [$\exists x(Fx\wedge\neg Gx)\checkmark$,ass
        [{$\neg\exists x\exists y((Fx\wedge Fy)\wedge\neg x=y)\checkmark$},ass
        [{$\forall x\neg\exists y((Fx\wedge Fy)\wedge\neg x=y)$},ass
        [$(Fa\wedge Ga)\checkmark$,ass
        [$(Fb\wedge\neg Gb)\checkmark$,ass
        [$Fa$,ass
        [$Ga$,ass
        [$Fb$,ass
        [$\neg Gb$,ass
        [{$\neg\exists y((Fa\wedge Fy)\wedge\neg a=y)\checkmark$},ass
        [{$\forall y\neg((Fa\wedge Fy)\wedge\neg a=y)$},ass
        [{$\neg((Fa\wedge Fb)\wedge\neg a=b)\checkmark$},ass
        [$\neg(Fa\wedge Fb)$
        [$\neg Fa$ [*,ass]] [$\neg Fb$ [*,ass]]]
        [{$\neg\neg a=b$}
        [{$a=b$},ass
        [$\neg Ga$,ass [*,ass]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
    \pagebreak
  \item Whoever stole the goods, knew the safe combination. Someone
    stole the goods, and only Jack knew the safe combination. Hence
    Jack stole the goods.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\forall x(Sx\supset Cx)$
        [$\exists xSx\checkmark$,ass
        [$\forall x(Cx\equiv x{=}j)$,ass
        [$\neg Sj$,ass
        [$Sa$,ass
        [$(Sa\supset Ca)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg Sa$ [*,ass]] [$Ca$
        [$(Ca\equiv a{=}j)\checkmark$,ass
        [$(Ca\supset a{=}j)\checkmark$,ass
        [$(a{=}j\supset Ca)$,ass
        [$\neg Ca$ [*,ass]] [$a{=}j$
        [$\neg Sa$,ass [*,ass]]]]]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item For every number, there’s a larger one. No number is larger than
    itself. So for every number, there’s a distinct number which is
    larger than it.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\forall x\exists y(Lyx)$
        [$\forall x\neg Lxx$,ass
        [$\neg\forall x\exists y(Lyx\wedge\neg y{=}x)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\exists x\neg\exists y(Lyx\wedge\neg y{=}x)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg\exists y(Lya\wedge\neg y{=}a)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\forall y\neg(Lya\wedge\neg y{=}a)$,ass
        [$\exists yLya\checkmark$,ass
        [$Lba$,ass
        [$\neg(Lba\wedge\neg b{=}a)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg Lba$ [*,ass]] [$\neg\neg b{=}a\checkmark$
        [$b{=}a$,ass
        [$Laa$,ass
        [$\neg Laa$,ass [*,ass]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \end{enumerate}
  \pagebreak
\item Show that the following wffs are q-logical truths
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item $\forall x\forall y(x{=}y\supset(Fx\supset Fy))$
  \item $\forall y\forall z(y{=}z\supset(\forall x(Lxy\wedge Fy)\supset
    \forall x(Lxz\wedge Fz)))$
  \end{enumerate}
  Thinking about the structure of these proofs, conclude that each way of filling out
  the following schema from §33.1 does indeed yield a q-logical truth:
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item[(LS)] $\forall v\forall w(v=w\supset(C(\ldots v\ldots v\ldots)\supset
    C(\ldots w\ldots w\ldots)))$
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{sol}
    \leavevmode

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $\forall x\forall y(x{=}y\supset(Fx\supset Fy))$

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\neg\forall x\forall y(x{=}y\supset(Fx\supset Fy))\checkmark$
        [$\exists x\neg\forall y(x{=}y\supset(Fx\supset Fy))\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg\forall y(a{=}y\supset(Fa\supset Fy))\checkmark$,ass
        [$\exists y\neg(a{=}y\supset(Fa\supset Fy))\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg(a{=}b\supset(Fa\supset Fb))$,ass
        [$a{=}b$,ass
        [$\neg(Fa\supset Fb)\checkmark$,ass
        [$Fa$,ass
        [$\neg Fb$,ass
        [$Fb$,ass [*,ass]]]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
      \enlargethispage{4\baselineskip}
    \item $\forall y\forall z(y{=}z\supset(\forall x(Lxy\wedge Fy)\supset
      \forall x(Lxz\wedge Fz)))$

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\neg\forall y\forall z(y{=}z\supset(\forall x(Lxy\wedge Fy)\supset
        \forall x(Lxz\wedge Fz)))\checkmark$
        [$\exists y\neg\forall z(y{=}z\supset(\forall x(Lxy\wedge Fy)\supset
        \forall x(Lxz\wedge Fz)))\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg\forall z(a{=}z\supset(\forall x(Lxa\wedge Fa)\supset
        \forall x(Lxz\wedge Fz)))\checkmark$,ass
        [$\exists z\neg(a{=}z\supset(\forall x(Lxa\wedge Fa)\supset
        \forall x(Lxz\wedge Fz)))\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg(a{=}b\supset(\forall x(Lxa\wedge Fa)\supset
        \forall x(Lxb\wedge Fb)))\checkmark$,ass
        [$a{=}b$,ass
        [$\neg(\forall x(Lxa\wedge Fa)\supset\forall x(Lxb\wedge Fb))\checkmark$,ass
        [$\forall x(Lxa\wedge Fa)$,ass
        [$\neg\forall x(Lxb\wedge Fb)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\exists x\neg(Lxb\wedge Fb)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg(Lcb\wedge Fb)$,ass
        [$(Lca\wedge Fa)\checkmark$,ass
        [$Lca$,ass
        [$Fa$,ass
        [$\neg Lcb$
        [$Lcb$,ass [*,ass]]]
        [$\neg Fb$
        [$Fb$,ass [*,ass]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{sol}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Put a `\thispagestyle{empty}` after `\enlargethispage`.

Comment: You could shift the proof a bit to the right or left if there's horizontal space so that it would overlap with the footer without clashing with the actual content of the footer. David's solution is probably better, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\small` to make things smaller (but harder to read:-) or use `\thspagestyle{empty}` to lose the page number, but assuming you don't want to do that you can play with the white space to make things fit (almost).

here I use `\enlargethispage*` rather than `\enlaregethispage` so white space shrinks as much as possible, and then adjusted the white space around enumerations using the `enumitem` options.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\bfseries\Alph*,align=left,leftmargin=*,
  labelsep=1.5em}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*.,labelindent=1em,labelsep=1.5em,
  leftmargin=*}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  ass/.append style={
    before computing xy={l=\baselineskip},
    no edge
  },
  prooftree/.style={
    baseline,
    for tree={
      child anchor=north,
      parent anchor=south
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Exercises 35}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Use \textbf{QL\textsuperscript{=}} trees to show the following inferences are valid:
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Jack is Fingers. Fingers is never caught. Whoever is never caught
    escapes justice. So Jack escapes justice.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [{$j=f$}
        [$\neg Cf$,ass
        [$\forall x(\neg Cx\supset Ex)$,ass
        [$\neg Ej$,ass
        [$(\neg Cf\supset Ef)$,ass
        [$\neg\neg Cf$ [*,ass]] [$Ef$
        [$Ej$,ass [*,ass]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item There is a wise philosopher. There is a philosopher who isn’t wise.
    So there are at least two philosophers.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\exists x(Fx\wedge Gx)\checkmark$
        [$\exists x(Fx\wedge\neg Gx)\checkmark$,ass
        [{$\neg\exists x\exists y((Fx\wedge Fy)\wedge\neg x=y)\checkmark$},ass
        [{$\forall x\neg\exists y((Fx\wedge Fy)\wedge\neg x=y)$},ass
        [$(Fa\wedge Ga)\checkmark$,ass
        [$(Fb\wedge\neg Gb)\checkmark$,ass
        [$Fa$,ass
        [$Ga$,ass
        [$Fb$,ass
        [$\neg Gb$,ass
        [{$\neg\exists y((Fa\wedge Fy)\wedge\neg a=y)\checkmark$},ass
        [{$\forall y\neg((Fa\wedge Fy)\wedge\neg a=y)$},ass
        [{$\neg((Fa\wedge Fb)\wedge\neg a=b)\checkmark$},ass
        [$\neg(Fa\wedge Fb)$
        [$\neg Fa$ [*,ass]] [$\neg Fb$ [*,ass]]]
        [{$\neg\neg a=b$}
        [{$a=b$},ass
        [$\neg Ga$,ass [*,ass]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
    \pagebreak
  \item Whoever stole the goods, knew the safe combination. Someone
    stole the goods, and only Jack knew the safe combination. Hence
    Jack stole the goods.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\forall x(Sx\supset Cx)$
        [$\exists xSx\checkmark$,ass
        [$\forall x(Cx\equiv x{=}j)$,ass
        [$\neg Sj$,ass
        [$Sa$,ass
        [$(Sa\supset Ca)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg Sa$ [*,ass]] [$Ca$
        [$(Ca\equiv a{=}j)\checkmark$,ass
        [$(Ca\supset a{=}j)\checkmark$,ass
        [$(a{=}j\supset Ca)$,ass
        [$\neg Ca$ [*,ass]] [$a{=}j$
        [$\neg Sa$,ass [*,ass]]]]]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item For every number, there’s a larger one. No number is larger than
    itself. So for every number, there’s a distinct number which is
    larger than it.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\forall x\exists y(Lyx)$
        [$\forall x\neg Lxx$,ass
        [$\neg\forall x\exists y(Lyx\wedge\neg y{=}x)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\exists x\neg\exists y(Lyx\wedge\neg y{=}x)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg\exists y(Lya\wedge\neg y{=}a)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\forall y\neg(Lya\wedge\neg y{=}a)$,ass
        [$\exists yLya\checkmark$,ass
        [$Lba$,ass
        [$\neg(Lba\wedge\neg b{=}a)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg Lba$ [*,ass]] [$\neg\neg b{=}a\checkmark$
        [$b{=}a$,ass
        [$Laa$,ass
        [$\neg Laa$,ass [*,ass]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \end{enumerate}
  \pagebreak
\item Show that the following wffs are q-logical truths
  \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt]
  \item $\forall x\forall y(x{=}y\supset(Fx\supset Fy))$
  \item $\forall y\forall z(y{=}z\supset(\forall x(Lxy\wedge Fy)\supset
    \forall x(Lxz\wedge Fz)))$
  \end{enumerate}
  Thinking about the structure of these proofs, conclude that each way of filling out
  the following schema from §33.1 does indeed yield a q-logical truth:
  \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt]
  \item[(LS)] $\forall v\forall w(v=w\supset(C(\ldots v\ldots v\ldots)\supset
    C(\ldots w\ldots w\ldots)))$
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{sol}
    \leavevmode
    \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt,itemindent=-75pt]
    \item $\forall x\forall y(x{=}y\supset(Fx\supset Fy))$

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\neg\forall x\forall y(x{=}y\supset(Fx\supset Fy))\checkmark$
        [$\exists x\neg\forall y(x{=}y\supset(Fx\supset Fy))\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg\forall y(a{=}y\supset(Fa\supset Fy))\checkmark$,ass
        [$\exists y\neg(a{=}y\supset(Fa\supset Fy))\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg(a{=}b\supset(Fa\supset Fb))$,ass
        [$a{=}b$,ass
        [$\neg(Fa\supset Fb)\checkmark$,ass
        [$Fa$,ass
        [$\neg Fb$,ass
        [$Fb$,ass [*,ass]]]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
      \enlargethispage*{4\baselineskip}
    \item $\forall y\forall z(y{=}z\supset(\forall x(Lxy\wedge Fy)\supset
      \forall x(Lxz\wedge Fz)))$

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\neg\forall y\forall z(y{=}z\supset(\forall x(Lxy\wedge Fy)\supset
        \forall x(Lxz\wedge Fz)))\checkmark$
        [$\exists y\neg\forall z(y{=}z\supset(\forall x(Lxy\wedge Fy)\supset
        \forall x(Lxz\wedge Fz)))\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg\forall z(a{=}z\supset(\forall x(Lxa\wedge Fa)\supset
        \forall x(Lxz\wedge Fz)))\checkmark$,ass
        [$\exists z\neg(a{=}z\supset(\forall x(Lxa\wedge Fa)\supset
        \forall x(Lxz\wedge Fz)))\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg(a{=}b\supset(\forall x(Lxa\wedge Fa)\supset
        \forall x(Lxb\wedge Fb)))\checkmark$,ass
        [$a{=}b$,ass
        [$\neg(\forall x(Lxa\wedge Fa)\supset\forall x(Lxb\wedge Fb))\checkmark$,ass
        [$\forall x(Lxa\wedge Fa)$,ass
        [$\neg\forall x(Lxb\wedge Fb)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\exists x\neg(Lxb\wedge Fb)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\neg(Lcb\wedge Fb)$,ass
        [$(Lca\wedge Fa)\checkmark$,ass
        [$Lca$,ass
        [$Fa$,ass
        [$\neg Lcb$
        [$Lcb$,ass [*,ass]]]
        [$\neg Fb$
        [$Fb$,ass [*,ass]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{sol}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```